# trying to use Java Spring AOP throws "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop

I am trying to get a simple AOP example working on my IDE.

below is my code.

I am getting this error below.

Please help me understand why..

***org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]***

AotSpringMain

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AotSpringMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(AotSpringMain.class, args);
        HumanFactory humanFactory = (HumanFactory)ctx.getBean("humanFactory");
        System.out.println(humanFactory.getFemale().getName());
        humanFactory.getFemale().setName("aaa");
        System.out.println(humanFactory.getFemale().getName());

    }
}
```

LoggingAspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.my_aop_example.HumanFactory.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {

        System.out.println("Log before start");
        System.out.println("Name: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("Log before end");

    }

}
```

HumanFactory

```
package com.my_aop_example;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HumanFactory {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Male")
    Human Male;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Female")
    Human female;

    public Human getMale() {
        return Male;
    }

    public Human getFemale() {
        return female;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no parameter `Object result`

```
  @Before("execution(* com.my_aop_example.HumanFactory.*(..))")
  public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

    System.out.println("Log before start");
    System.out.println("Name: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("Log before end");

  }
```